# Cauchy Riemann Equations -- Polar Coordinates

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

I want to show that the statement $f$ analytic and the Cauchy-Riemann equations in polar form are satisfied are equivalent statements.

If we express $z$ in polar coordinates then $z = re^{i\theta}$ and $$f(z) = u(r,\theta) + iv(r,\theta)$$ If $\triangle z = (r + \triangle r)e^{i\theta} - re^{i\theta}$ then $\triangle z \to 0 $ if and only if $\triangle r \to 0$ and $$\frac{f(z + \triangle z) - f(z)}{\triangle z} = \frac{u(r+\triangle r, \theta) + iv(r+\triangle r, \theta) - i(u(r,\theta) + iv(r,\theta))}{\triangle r e^{i\theta}}$$

Why is it $i(u(r,\theta) + iv(r,\theta))$ instead of $-u(r,\theta)-iv(r,\theta))$? Why are we multiplying by an $i$?

I'm attempting to follow: http://people.math.gatech.edu/~meyer/MA6701/module20.pdf (page 4)

Comment: Appears to be just a typo in the source.

Comment: Ah. Okay. Thank!